# Apache CXF Samples - Can't find bundle for base name org/apache/xml/security/resource/xmlsecurity, locale pl_PL

Tags: java, cxf, ws-security

I am trying to run Apache CXF Sample ws_security/ut (https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/tags/cxf-3.0.0-milestone2/distribution/src/main/release/samples/ws_security/ut/) using mvn -Pserver everything starts fine however when I make request to webservice using the SoapUI I get the following response:

```
<soap:Fault>
    <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
    <faultstring>Can't find bundle for base name 
         org/apache/xml/security/resource/xmlsecurity, locale pl_PL
    </faultstring>
</soap:Fault>
```

What should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: How can we reproduce problem?

Comment: To reproduce the problem checkout project from SVN (samples from link above) and then navigate to ws_security/ut directory and run from there mvn -Pserver, then open soap ui and make request to webservice.

Comment: It's a bug in 3.0.0-milestone2. Just use 3.0.0 or 3.0.1 instead. BTW CXF does not use SVN any more: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cxf.git